# JSTUN vs PJNATH

Tags: node.js, serverside-javascript, ice, stun

I'm going to be writing my own STUN implementation in JavaScript (server-side with NodeJS), and I'm looking for a library to base my code on.

I have found both JSTUN and PJNATH, and both seem to be supported by members of stackoverflow.  I downloaded the source for both, and PJNATH was about 15,000 lines of code whereas JSTUN was less than 3000.

Is one library more complete than the other?

I need both server and client components, and I would like to be as feature-complete as possible because I do NOT want to implement TURN (too hardware intensive).

Is there a better library that I should be looking at?  Ultimately I want to make a completely ICE complient solution, but STUN is enough for now.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? Were you successful in writing the STUN impl in JavaScript?

Comment: @pkrish - Not yet. It wasn't super high priority and other things came up, but I will probably get back to this in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know, JSTUN is not a complete solution. This is what they have mentioned in their site.They want to add support for RFC 5389.Please check their web site(http://jstun.javawi.de/).